# I want to manipulate the file in MarkLogic using Python

Tags: python-2.7, marklogic, marklogic-8

```
declareUpdate();

//get Docs
myDoc = cts.doc("/heal/scripts/Test.json").toObject();

//add Data
myDoc.prescribedPlayer =
  [
    {
      "default": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?vu003dhYB0mn5zh2c"
    }
  ]

//persist
xdmp.documentInsert("/heal/scripts/Test.json",myDoc,null,"scripts")
```

Comment: I wish to get the above code in python.

Comment: I'd advice looking into https://github.com/marklogic/python_api

Comment: @grtjn I tried with that one but it is supporting only python 3 and I am working in python 2.7

Comment: Then consider looking at the [REST Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/client), and making HTTP calls to that yourself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Ankur Please check below python method,

```
def PartialUpdateData(self,filename, content, context):
   self.querystring = {"uri": "/" + self.collection + "/" + filename}
   url = self.baseUri
   self.header = {'Content-Type': "application/json"}

   mydata = {
               "patch":[{ "insert": {
               "context": context,
               "position": "before",
               "content": content
            }}]}
   resp = requests.patch(url + "/documents", data=json.dumps(mydata),
                       headers=self.header, auth=self.auth, params=self.querystring)
   return resp.content
```

I hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: are you converting data in string, or passing in json format?

Comment: Converting dictionary to json using "json.dumps".

Answer (score 2):

You're looking to add a new JSON property. You can do that using a REST Client API request, sending [a PATCH command](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PATCH/v1/documents). Use [an `insert` instruction](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_65730) in the patch.

See the note in [Specifying Position in JSON](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_95121), which indicates that

> You cannot use last-child to insert a property as an immediate child of the root node of a document. Use before or after instead. For details, see [Limitations of JSON Path Expressions](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/documents#id_13293).

Instead, your patch will look something like:

```
{
  "insert": {
    "context": "/topProperty",
    "position": "after",
    "content": 
      [
        {
          "default": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?vu003dhYB0mn5zh2c"
        }
      ],
  }
}
```

where `topProperty` is a JSON property that is part of the root node of the JavaScript object you want to update.

If that approach is problematic (for instance, if there is no topProperty that's reliably available), you could also do a sequence of operations:

- [retrieve the document](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents)
- edit the content in Python
- [update the document in the database](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/documents)

With this approach, there is the possibility that some other process may update the document while you're working on it. You can either rely on [optimistic locking](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_81051) or a [multi-statement transaction](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_79848) to work around that, depending on the potential consequences of someone else doing a write.